# При дублировании таблицы не срабатывает javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

pta-ua.com
Необходимо сделать 2 рейтинга на сайте. Один среди парных игроков, другой среди одиночных. Сейчас рейтинг работает автоматически, при смене значения количества очков игрок автоматически поднимается выше. 
Когда я копирую этот же html код с теми же данными и дублирую , скрипт перестает работать. Сортирует только тот, который выше в коде. 
Вот js код

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
 { 
  $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[2,1], [0,0]]} );
  $("#myTable").tablesorter( {debug:false} );
 $('table').tablesorter({ headers: { 0: { sorter: false}, 1: {sorter: false} } }); 
} 
);
 $(function() {
    // add new widget called indexFirstColumn
    $.tablesorter.addWidget({
        // give the widget a id
        id: "indexFirstColumn",
        // format is called when the on init and when a sorting has finished
        format: function(table) {               
            // loop all tr elements and set the value for the first column  
            for(var i=0; i < table.tBodies[0].rows.length; i++) {
                $("tbody tr:eq(" + i + ") td:first",table).html(i+1);
            }                                   
        }
    });

    $("table").tablesorter({
        widgets: ['zebra','indexFirstColumn']
    });
    var button = document.getElementById('showAll');
    table = document.getElementById('myTable');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Проверяем на наличие класса и  вызываем соответсвуюущую функцию
  table.classList.contains('opened') ? hideRows()  : showRows();
});

function showRows() {
  table.classList.add('opened');
  button.innerHTML = 'Скрыть';
}
function hideRows() {
  table.classList.remove('opened');
  button.innerHTML = 'Показать весь рейтинг';
}
});
```

```html
HTML код
 
<table id ="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
          <thead> 
            <tr> 
              <th>№</th> 
              <th>Фамилия Имя</th> 
              <th class="header headerSortUp">Очки</th> 
            </tr> 
          </thead> 
          <tbody class="selected"> 
            <tr> 
              <td>1</td> 
              <td>Фамилия Имя</td> 
              <td>524</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
              <td>2</td> 
              <td>Фамилия Имя</td> 
              <td>119</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
              <td>3</td> 
              <td>Фамилия Имя</td> 
              <td>263</td> 
            </tr>
            
            

          </tbody> 
        </table>
```

Comment: У вас скрипт привязан к id-таблицы "myTable", поэтому ваш скрипт работает только с одной таблицей

Comment: И что нужно сделать? Допустим  скопировал эту же таблицу и разместил на той же страницы рядом и изменил id на "myTable2". Как будет выглядеть js код в таком случае?